# What's the difference between "grammatical mistake" and "grammatical error"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "**grammatical mistake**" and "**grammatical error**"?

Based on Cambridge dictionary:

**[Mistake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mistake)**:  an action, decision, or judgment that produces an unwanted or unintentional result.

**[Error](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/error)**: a mistake.

Does it mean that I can use both (grammatical mistake and grammatical error) **interchangeably** and they are just synonyms or a matter of taste?

The context is for example when I see that there's no an article in a place where it should be `(e.g. "He took table." instead "He took a table")` or when I see missing of s' in 3rd person singular verb in present simple tense `(e.g. "He learn English" instead of "He learns English")` etc. and I want to say that it is a grammatical error / mistake.

Google Ngram viewer shows much more results for grammatical error, does it say that it is favorable in my context too?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Grammatical mistake** and **grammatical error** have no semantic difference. They are used interchangeably. Between the two, **grammatical error** is much more common. Here's a Google Ngram chart that shows their popularity.

[image]

Note that **grammar error** and **grammar mistake** are also used, but are less common than their respective adjectival versions. See below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you1+^, When I saw your answer for the first time I immediately checked google Ngram to see if they are equal in use, and I found that you also added it. I edited my question to make the issue clearer.

Comment: But I think there is some difference. An "error" just means it is wrong. A "mistake" is an error made by someone. Errors happen but people make mistakes.

Comment: @user3169 - In my experience, most people don't make that distinction, and "error" and "mistake" are pretty much interchangeable.